# sanitize_sql_array is adding extra, unnecessary quotes to query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, hstore

This is the first time I've seen this issue. I'm building up an SQL array to run through sanitize_sql_array and Rails is adding extra, unnecessary single quotes in the return value. So instead of returning:

```
SELECT DISTINCT data -> 'Foo' from products
```

it returns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT data -> ''Foo'' from products
```

which of course Postgres doesn't like.

Here is the code:

```
sql_array = ["SELECT DISTINCT %s from products", "data -> 'Foo'"]
sql_array = sanitize_sql_array(sql_array)
connection.select_values(sql_array)
```

Note the same thing happens when I use the shorter and more usual:

```
sql_array = ["SELECT DISTINCT %s from products", "data -> 'Foo'"]
connection.select_values(send(:sanitize_sql_array, sql_array))
```

Ever seen this before? Does it have something to do with using HStore? I definitely need that string sanitized since the string Foo is actually coming from a user-entered variable.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? That `"data -> 'Foo'"` argument doesn't make sense to me. Otherwise the [`sanitize_sql_array`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_array) is working correctly.

Comment: Milen: this is hstore syntax in postgres. select distinct data -> 'Foo' from products means to select the values in the key,value store called data where the key is equal to Foo. postgres requires that the key be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're giving `sanitize_sql_array` a string that contains an hstore expression and expecting `sanitize_sql_array` to understand that the string contains some hstore stuff; that's asking far too much, `sanitize_sql_array` only knows about simple things like strings and numbers, it doesn't know how to parse PostgreSQL's SQL extensions or even standard SQL. How would you expect `sanitize_sql_array` to tell the difference between, for example, a string that happens to contain `'11 * 23'` and a string that is supposed to represent the arithmetical expression `11 * 23`?

You should split your `data -> 'Foo'` into two pieces so that `sanitize_sql_array` only sees the string part when it is sanitizing things:

```
sql_array = [ 'select distinct data -> ? from products', 'Foo' ]
sql = sanitize_sql_array(sql_array)
```

That will give you the SQL you're looking for:

```
select distinct data -> 'Foo' from products
```

Comment: I agree that this is not the specialty of sanitize_sql_array, but that solution doesn't work either. Postgres requires single quotes around 'Foo' and your way returns 'select distinct data -> Foo from products' which doesn't have them.

Comment: @RobGonzalez: Are you using `%s` or `?` in the SQL?

Comment: I'm using %s. ? produces results that I don't understand at all.

Comment: `?` produces the results in my answer, I pasted that right out of my Rails console.

Comment: what's the difference between those? i think you're right but i'm trying to understand why.

Comment: The difference is that `?` takes care of all the type issues for you (strings will be quoted, numbers won't be, dates will be formatted properly, booleans will match the database's representation, ...) but `%s` just throws an escaped string into the SQL without quoting it and `%s` would probably treat everything as a string regardless of what data type it really is.